# characteristic polynomial without associated matrix(Gaussian sums)

Tags: abstract-algebra, characters

Suppose a irreducible monic polynomial in $ \mathbb {F} _q $ and suppose that f has $ deg (f) $ nonzero roots in an extension E of $ \mathbb{F}_q $
The book wrote:
"each root b of has its polynomial over F_q the polynomial
$$f(x)^\frac{s}{deg(f)} = x^s-c_{1}x^s-1 + \ldots + (-1)^{s}c_s $$

How is the characteristic polynomial of a root defined b?
the book also says that $c_1 = Tr_\frac{E}{\mathbb{F}_q}(b)$

I do not know what characteristic polynomial is associated with a root of another polynomial and much less how it found $ c_1 $
The book is "Finite Fields", content of Gaussian sums

Comment: Nothing you have quoted says "characteristic polynomial". Seems more like they're talking about the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Since there was a mention of the trace map, it is possible they are referring to the characteristic polynomial of the matrix associated to multiplication by this root seen as a linear transformation on the vector space $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Although I find the quote hard to parse due to what looks like typos, in particular not sure what $s$ is.